# Possible swap map elements without copy?

Tags: c++

I have a `map<int,map<int,string>>  themap`

I would like to swap elements themap[1] and themap[2].  But the inside maps `map<int,string>` are very big so I don't want them copied.  Is there way to do this or do I have to change themap to use pointers.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [`std::map::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/swap) for the outer map:

> `void swap( map& other );`
>
> Exchanges the contents of the container with those of other. Does not invoke any move, copy, or swap operations on individual elements.

Answer (score 3):

```
themap[1].swap(themap[2]);
```

This won't copy, or even move, any elements in the maps. It will likely just swap ownership of the root node, just a few pointer assignments.

Comment: Right answer, badly explained.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) since it has a specialization for `std::map` (and many other containers and library types).

```
std::swap(themap[1], themap[2]);
```

It does call [`std::map::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/swap2) but I think it's useful to get in the habit of using `std::swap` and trusting the standard committee and library implementers to do the right thing.

Comment: Suppose no swap existed, either map one or std::swap.  Could a person write their own?  Or do we need access to private map members ?

Comment: If you are creating your own types the expected method is to write a non-member `swap` in the same namespace as your type. Then the client code will write `using std::swap; swap(a, b);`. This will find your non-member swap, `std::swap` specialization, or other matching function through overload resolution and argument-dependent lookup. See this [cppreference page on the swappable concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Swappable).